# How to synchronize web content and nginx configuration on debian

Tags: debian, nginx, load-balancer

I have a web server (server1) with nginx and php on a debian machine. I have created another server (server2) that has the same web content and nginx configuration of server1.

These servers are behind an nginx reverse proxy that I want to configure as a load balancer. So I need that web content and nginx configuration of server1 and server2 are always the same.

What is the best practice to make the two servers synchronized when I make some changes on server1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a cron job with rsync on server1 feeding any changes to server2